# Adding roles functionality enables admin consent in Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have an Azure AD multi tenant application which has a single role defined and enabled. Also, none of the permissions I have defined require admin consent.

Case 1: Roles are disabled on the other tenant

All users from the other tenant can login to the app. I believe that is because the permissions that I have set do not require admin consent.

Case 2: Roles are enabled on the other tenant

Even after a role is assigned to a non-admin user, the user is not able to login. He sees a screen showing that admin consent is required. However, once the admin from the other tenant has logged in once, users in the other tenant are able to login. I am not sure why.

Are the admin consent and app roles functionality related? The desired behavior is even if roles are assigned and enabled, admins shouldn't need to login and give consent since the permissions set by the developer don't need admin consent. Can someone tell me how can I achieve the desired behavior? I don't want to add another button for admin to 'signup' before others can 'signin'. Also, I can't move to v2 endpoint as I believe it does not have the roles functionality and other possible limitations.

Customer Tenant

[image]

Token request using OpenIdConnect

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                new OpenIdConnectOptions()
                {
                    AutomaticChallenge = true,
                    ClientId = [ClientId],
                    Authority = [AADInstance],
                    CallbackPath = [CallbackPath],
                    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters(
                        SaveSigninToken = true;            
                        ValidateIssuer = true;
                        // Custom validator for issuer/tenant
                        IssuerValidator = ValidateIssuerValue;
                        RoleClaimType = ClaimTypes.Role;
                    ),
                    Events = new CustomOpenIdConnectEvents()
                } );
```

Thanks

-Ravi

Answer (score 0):

> Are the admin consent and app roles functionality related?

No, it is not related. The real possible reason for other users not able to consent for the application maybe the admin of their tenants disable this behavior. You can refer this settings from figure below:
[image]

> The desired behavior is even if roles are assigned and enabled, admins shouldn't need to login and give consent since the permissions set by the developer don't need admin consent. Can someone tell me how can I achieve the desired behavior? I don't want to add another button for admin to 'signup' before others can 'signin'.

This is the desired feature by default unless the admin disable users to consent the third-party application.

And below links also are helpful for this topic:
[Application roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/multitenant-identity/app-roles)

[Understanding user and admin consent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devhowto-multi-tenant-overview#understanding-user-and-admin-consent)

In-addition, you can refer the [Entity and complex type reference | Graph API reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#oauth2permission-type) to see the  `OAuth2Permission` and `AppRole` to about the entity type.

### Update

[image]

Comment: I double checked the setting you indicated. Still it doesnt work. After assigning user a role, when I try to login with that user I get the following message.                                                                                              "You can't access this application "APP XYZ" needs permission to access resources in your organization that only an admin can grant. Please ask an admin to grant permission to this app before you can use it.

Comment: Did you grant any other resource to this app?

Comment: Am not sure what you mean by assigning resource. I don't think i have.  How can I check?

Comment: You can check it via Azure portal->App registrations->{Your App}->Required permissions. What's resource and detailed scope it had been granted? If there are some permission that require admin to consent, you may get this error.

Comment: Checked. There aren't ant permissions that require admin consent.

Comment: Would you minding share the detailed resource and scope you have granted for this app and the exact request for the token?

Comment: Updated the question. Let me know if you need more information. For requesting the token i am using OpenIdConnect (graph api). Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes, you may share the URL authorization/token request. In-addition, would you mind also sharing the figure that under the **Required permissions** of this app? And did this issue occur when the users on your own tenant or other tenants to consent this application since you mentioned this is multi-tenant app?

Comment: Updated the question. This issue occurs when other tenants try to login to the application.

Comment: If this issue is relative to the other tenants, then the settings **Users can consent to apps accessing company data on their behalf** on your tenant will not affect this behavior. The settings on the relative tenant should enable it if they expect the normal users can consent this application.

Comment: Oh that setting is enabled on the customer/relative  tenant. And the users of the external/customer tenant are still being asked for admin consent. This is happening if I  (developer tenant) have roles defined for the application.

Comment: Did you mean the normal user still not able to give the grant? And would you mind also sharing the haring the figure that under the **Required permissions** of this app?

Comment: Yes. normal user is still not able to give the grant. Question updated with the image for the app permissions on the customer tenant side.

Comment: It seems there are some misunderstanding. To clarify the figure mentioned in the previews conversation, I update a demo figure for your reference.